# Casting simple generic objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have a method that I created for simplifying using HttpClient calls. it uses the method     HttpReponse.Content.ReadAsAsync().Result to get the response from the API.

This all works fine. My method looks something like this:

```
    public static T ExecuteAPIGetRequest<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //basic authentication

        var t = new object();
        string baseURL =  "myurl"; 

        //Execute request
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(baseURL).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;  
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)t;
        }
    }
```

My question is, if the query fails it needs to return an empty type of T. This is fine if its a custom class I have written, but it does not work for objects like string or string[]. Any ideas?

Cheers

NCBL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to return `default(T)`

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;  
}
else
{
    return default(T);
}
```

[default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will return `null` for reference types, and zeros numeric values `int`, `double`, etc.. and corresponding default values for custom `struct` and `enum`.

Daniel kindly noted one issue: if for reference types you want to return **default object** and not **null**, you should define generic constraint `new T()`. Now you can instantiate object of type `T` using call to parameter-less constructor. Full method is given below:

```
public static T ExecuteAPIGetRequest<T>(string url, 
                                        Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
                                                                   where T : new()
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    //basic authentication

    string baseURL =  "myurl"; 

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(baseURL).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;  
    }
    else
    {
        return new T(); //returns an instance, not null
    }
}
```

Now you will return default object for reference types, not null. Open type `T` can only take types, which have constructor by default (without parameters)

Comment: Please note: This will be `null` if `T` is a reference type, which it most likely is. If you want to return a default *instance* you need to add a `new` constraint to `T` and `return new T();` instead.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth maybe I'm missing something, but `default(T)` returns correct value for primitives and custom structs. I've just tested for `double` and custom struct. You don't need to specify generic constraint, struct will always have parameterless constructor

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: I am not talking about value types, I am talking about reference types. For these, it will return `null`. However, the OP is creating a new instance and tries to return that. To me, it looks like he wants to return an instance and not `null`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks a lot, I've got your comment. Will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Can I make a suggestion that you consider an approach like this....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var client = new HttpClient();

        //basic authentication

        string baseURL = "myurl";

        var link = Link<Foo>.Create(baseURL);

        var response = client.SendAsync(link.CreateRequest()).Result;

        var myfoo = link.ProcessResponse(response);

    }

}


public class Link<T>
{
    public Uri Target { get; set; }

    public static Link<T> Create(string url)
    {
        return new Link<T>() {Target = new Uri(url)};
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest()
    {
        return new HttpRequestMessage() {RequestUri = Target};
    }   

    public T ProcessResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            return new T(); //returns an instance, not null
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{

}
```

By encapsulating the mechanics of creating the link into a static factory method and the handling of the response into the ProcessResponse method you get a similar level of re-usability, but you also get the benefits of reusing the same HttpClient.  This allows you to actually take advantage of the DefaultRequestHeaders and it will stop HttpClient from keep closing the connection when it gets disposed.

Also, by avoiding wrapping the Async call inside a sync method, you can let the calling code decide whether to block for the result or handle it asynchronously.  You are likely to run into deadlock issues at some point with the way you are currently using .Result.

This technique of creating a Link class to encapsulate specific behaviour relating to de-referencing a URL can be extremely useful.  It is easy to add parameters that can be used to fill in URI templates.  You can also use it to handle request bodies.